# I am trying to run slam_gmapping on a separate device as my sensor nodes (robot), I can subscribe to the topics, but my published map is empty?

Tags: ros-melodic, gmapping, rplidar

I am new to ROS and I am working on a project for school.

I am using the HiWonder JetAuto (based on the Jetson Nano) to run my sensor nodes. Specifically the RPLidar A1, Astra Camera Pro Plus, IMU, and servo managers. From these sensors, I am getting all my required topics and frames, such as laser_scan, odom, imu_corrected, pose, etc.

I am trying to run slam_gmapping on a separate device (my laptop) and I am using the same ROS and Ubuntu (ROS Melodic, Ubuntu 18.04) version on that device. My map topic exists and is being published, but when using the "hz" command, no new messages are displayed. Furthermore, on rviz my map file is empty, and the warning is: "No map received". My map topic seems to be subscribing to all the required topics that gmapping needs but still there is not data. I've attached my rqt graph below (gmapping running on my laptop):
[image]

When I run gmapping on the robot itself, it seems to work fine, and I can see the map in rviz with no issues. I've attached the rqt graph of gmapping running on the robot itself below:
[image]

From my perspective it is a very small difference, but I am new to ROS so I have no idea why the map is not being made when the gmapping node is being run on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Quick troubleshooting.  If you try and echo the topic on the nodes, do you get output?

```
rostopic echo /map
```

If you do not get any output then it's possible it's not actually publishing the map due to a network configuration issue.

Make sure ROS_IP is set on all the nodes to their respective IP addresses.
Make sure `/etc/hosts` has entries for all the nodes' IP/hostname combinations in each other's files.